# jpa read only active records

Tags: java, jpa

I have a set of tables where I maintain an active_ind column and have a jpa entity mapped to it.

When I write queries I like to keep things simple and just do:
select d from Doctor where ...

Instead of:
select d from Doctor where d.activeInd='A' and ...

Is it possible to achieve the "where d.activeInd='A'" with annotations or do I always have to put it in the where clause?
It's kind of ok for a single entity but when I join with couple tables, it can become cumbersome.

Comment: JPA does NOT provide annotations to append arbitrary SQL segments to queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Hibernate as the JPA provider, you can use hibernate's `@Filter` annotation to filter out entities automatically in queries.

However if you need to stick to pure JPA, there's no equivalent yet although it has been wished (https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-87).

Comment: ok I guess better to just use hibernate than jpa since they offer more features. thanks

Comment: You can still use the @Filter annotation even if the rest of your code is JPA, it just means that your code isn't 100% JPA compatible.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to use JPA with Spring, and it's provide an DAO interface, that have the method find(id) and findAll(). You can even create your own method using the fields like findByFirstNameAndLastName().

I hope it helps.